# Did Simpsons predict President Trump's visit to Saudi Arabia?

Tags: divination

There is a picture attributed to Simpsons episode from early 2000's (I couldn't deny or confirm it yet after some search) which has been circulating on the Social media a lot:

[image]

Ridiculously, this pic is almost a carbon copy of the one at summit ([in Saudi Arabia](http://time.com/4778549/saudi-arabia-donald-trump-visit/) if I am not wrong?). So can someone confirm whether it was really aired in an episode of Simpons then or its fabricated one?

Comment: Snopes says: [**False**](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/simpsons-predict-trump-orb/). Simple David Hume-check... which is more likely: that an animated show managed to extremely accurately predict a very specific event 15 years in the future, or that **someone posted false claims on Facebook**... which is more likely?

Comment: There is no claim here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Simpsons creators are eerily good at predicting the future, and in this case both the picture and screen grab of the cartoon are accurate, however mis-attributed. It is not from a 2002 episode, it is from a 2017 video posted to the Simpsons facebook page *after* Trump's visit to Saudi Arabia.

---

The photograph, as we know, is of President Trump, Saudi King Salman bin Abdulaziz, and Egyptian President Abdel Fatah al-Sisi at the Global Center for Combating Extremist Ideology in Riyadh, Saudi Arabia in May 2017

The [video](https://youtu.be/21lhiKfc1p4) was posted to Facebook on 26th May 2017

Comment: Picture appears about 5 seconds into the video